# I registered my domain, but it doesn't appear to exist

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration

I wanted to register a domain with No-Ip and clicked the Sign Up button on their homepage.  I entered my desired domain name (I won't publish it until I get this resolved, to prevent "domain theft"), then clicked Add my domain. I completed the order form, and waited 72 hours like it said, but my domain is still not active. Any help? Did I register my domain correctly?

Comment: What exactly is happening? Does no-ip tell you the domain doesn't exist, or is it having problems resolving the server? You usually have to run something on your server to regularly update no-ip with the correct ip address. You might also want to make sure that your web provider allows inbound traffic on port 80 (some providers prevent users from hosting sites)

Comment: WHOIS query: Whois Server Version 2.0

No match for domain domainname.

Answer (score 1):

First, do a [WHOIS](http://www.whois.sc/) lookup of your domain name to see if it's listed as registered. If it's *not* registered but you received a confirmation of the order by email, contact your registrar for support.

If the domain *is* registered, it sounds like you haven't pointed the domain to a server yet, which is why you're not seeing a website when you visit the domain in your browser.

**To point the domain to your home computer,** follow [these instructions from no-ip.](http://www.no-ip.com/support/guides/other/using_cable_dsl_router.html)

**To point the domain name to a web server elsewhere,**  first purchase web hosting from a hosting company (search for 'shared hosting'). The welcome email from the web host will contain two or more 'nameservers', as well as an IP address. You need to enter the nameservers *or* the IP address in the no-ip control panel (depending on what options they give you there) to point the domain name to the web server.